# gtest output not appearing in visual studio output window after including msxml4

Tags: visual-studio, googletest, msxml4

I have gtest all setup and running fine with Visual Studio 8.

I've included msxml 4.0 in my build and now the test output won't show up in the visual studio output window.

- The application will run if launched from the command line and return correct results (no missing dlls)
- I've narrowed it down the msxml4.dll because if I comment  out the include section everything returns to normal

For reason beyond my control we are including the dll like so:

```
#import "msxml4.dll"
```

Any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio doesn't support gtest by default however, I've created a plugin for visual studio 2008, its not guaranteed to be perfect and there are probably still bugs in in it but the source is freely available under gpl license here: http://gamesfairy.co.uk/svn/vsgtest.

it will allow you to run google tests either through other windows->test list or by right clicking the marker beside the test and running it. the test result will appear both in the plugin's output folder and in the test list window.

If you do find bugs let me know and I'll try to fix them or if you want to fix them submit me the patch :).

hope this helps, though it doesn't answer why it stops appearing in the default output pane I know :$

Comment: thanks! Unfortunately I've complete moved off that platform (now mostly mac os and mobile and when I do windows desktop i don't use gtest anymore )